# Shell: make prompt # and $ uncopiable

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Often when invoking shell commands, one prepends a line with:

- `$` if the command has to be invoked by **user**
- `#` if the command has to be invoked by **root**

So you end-up writing things like:

```
# apt-get install nano
$ nano file.txt
```

Since these commands are intented to be copiable, it would be great if selecting the whole line would still not select the prompt character `#` or `$`.

edit: this is **VERY** similar of displaying non-copyable [line numbers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/why-are-there-no-line-numbers-in-the-code-listings).

Comment: So you want the system not to prevent copying the # from #!/bin/ksh for instance?

Comment: What would be even better is if users didn't blindly copy and paste from Stack Overflow. Why, exactly, would we want to facilitate this?

Comment: To be fair, I can see where this is coming from. When copying and pasting shell commands (and yes this is what people do - why type them by hand?) multiline commands get executed right away, resulting in failing commands. You have to repeat each command and often enough move the cursor to the beginning of each line using the keyboard. There's more productive uses for anyone's time. (That said, there's unlikely to be a workable implementation of this.)

Comment: `cat > stackoverflow_code.sh.tmp && cat stackoverflow_code.sh | sed 's/^#//g' > stackoverflow_code.sh`

Comment: That's not the point @RobertLongson @ParthianShot Your argument is silly. Is this *that* much complitcated to make a regex detect these scripts? `grep -v -E '^(\$|#) '` does the job…

Comment: The point is that it's not quite as easy as you're suggesting.

Comment: Yes, it would certainly be more complicated for Stack Overflow than using a regex. I imagine a number of my answers have `#` and `$` symbols in them, but I can guarantee you that *none* of them have *nix shell commands. False positives are killer here, and the benefit is exceedingly minor. As usual, whenever you use a regex to solve a problem, you end up with two problems.

Comment: That grep suggestion would throw away the whole line, by the way.

Comment: Copying shell scripts with comments will be so much fun with this.

Answer (score 22):

Honestly, this is a terrible idea all-around. The devs would have to deal with questions like:

- How would you tell that it's bash? In many languages, `$` is usable in variable names and `#` means a comment.
- How would this be implemented?

…all to save a grand total of 3 key presses (on many machines): <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>backspace</kbd>. It wouldn't even be for everything. The devs have much better things to do.

Comment: I almost disagree with everything you said. `grep -v -E '^(\$|#) '` does almost the job it's not *that hard*. It would save much more than 3 key presses, actually you would save `n-1` copies/pastes plus `3n` keypresses for `n` lines (you usually not copy only a single line). I guess i'm talking to the wrong ppl here.

Comment: @Cqnqrd the question of "how would this be implemented?" means "how would this be implemented *client-side*?" It's not like there's just some random Unicode character or HTML element that makes something uncopiable. Perhaps you could write a userscript or browser extension for this, but at 27 downvotes to 1 upvote, you can pretty much call this [status-declined].

Comment: I'm fine with downvotes from the ones disliking the idea (even if I don't see any good reason on this topic). The technical challenge is not a good reason.

Comment: @Cqnqrd why is the technical challenge not a good reason?

Comment: Much harder problem are solved everyday on SO and elsewhere - I just don't believe that this is the toughest problem of the year.

Comment: @Cqnqrd sure, it isn't. The problem is that it saves basically zero effort.

Comment: And that's the point: I disagree with that! ;)

Comment: I guess you're overestimating how often people copy/paste bash commands from Stack Overflow. Hint: for me it's basically zero.

Comment: Obviously you are basically copying zero SO cmds and that's precisely why I disagree with you. Experts don't need to copy/paste these commands, they actually write them! I'm not talking about experts here but newcomers who will, anyway, blindly copy/paste these commands no matter what your opinions are on that. SO is already full of ready-to-paste code snippets!

Comment: @Cqnqrd I'd like to point you to [this comment](/questions/339448/shell-make-prompt-and-uncopiable/339449?noredirect=1#comment420729_339448) on the above question.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Pseudo-elements are not copyable.

Comment: @Oriol I know. Sometimes being naïve helps, because it's actually mostly a coincidence that I even know what pseudo-elements even *are*.